# Inheritance in php page Object Oriented Application

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have one class for database, another class for the components in the website. I wish to inherit the methods from the database class.

My Question is should i always put require_once("databaseclass.php");
in the page or should i always write parent class and child class in the same .php page?  Will that pose calling functions error afterwards when my codes build up.

Thank you.

Comment: [You should read this](http://bd1.php.net/autoload).

Comment: Thank you. I'm so sleepy now. I think structuring and coding approach to application design is really what is bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do and how it is structured. Use the required_once() when you want to use function's from that database class in the current php page.

Comment: Thank you. I'm so sleepy now. I think structuring and coding approach to application design is really what is bothering me.